# How to schedule a task in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I want to schedule a task, say, sending an email, after 2 weeks in GAE. I know we can use **CountDownMillis** or **etaMillis** to schedule a task for later on (Java). Is it efficient? Are there better ways?
Also what is the upper limit of on scheduling using countDownMillis, *Long.MAX_VALUE*?

About doing it as a Cron job, the date for sending the email is not known initially. It's obtained from a user. Can we write to cron.xml as soon a new job is to be performed?

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Is 2 weeks an exact time period or is it sufficient to do the task on this day? On the 2nd opportunity, I'd saved the task to the db with the sheduled date of execution and retrieve it with an daily cron job and execute the task.

Comment: you can't write to any file in the files you've uploaded on GAE. So no. You can however create tasks that will execute in the future.

Comment: if the date cannot be known in advance, the "best" solution I can think of is a cron job that runs each day, checking in the datastore if an email is "due", and then sends it. When a user registers (or however) to send an email, then it's added to the datastore.

Comment: For the general case, I agree with @Patrice: store something in the DB, and use a cron to search for "due" tasks. For emailing users, though, I'd made the task run every 5 or 10 minutes, so you send users an email at about the same time they performed the action you are emailing them about

Comment: @marianosimone oh definitely it depends when he wants the email sent. I don't  know if it's an email for registration, or a report, or whatever. Hence the "one day". Time definitely should be adjusted on the use case ^^

Comment: I don't believe there's any special inefficiency in either `TaskOptions.countdownMillis` or `TaskOptions.etaMillis`  -- I'd use the former with a value of `7 * 86400 * 1000`, that's only just above 600 millions so it definitely won't hit any range limit (which in any case, as you opine, should be Long.MAX_VALUE to the best of my knowledge).